# Catch custom exception in Clojure

Tags: exception, clojure

In the [libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) library, the `PhoneNumberUtil.parse` function throws a `NumberParseException`. I'd like to handle this exception gracefully.

I'm running the following one-off script (invoked with `java -cp path/to/clojure.jar:path/to/libphonenumber.jar clojure.main -i scratch.clj`):

```
(import '(com.google.i18n.phonenumbers PhoneNumberUtil))

(defn parse-phone-no
  "Convert the phone number to standard form, using the libphonenumber class.
  Arguments:
    raw-phone-no - the phone number to convert
  Returns:
    the canonical version of the phone number, or nil if the phone number was 
    invalid."
  [raw-phone-no]
  (do 
    (def phone-util (PhoneNumberUtil/getInstance))
    (try
      (do
        (def us-number (.parse phone-util raw-phone-no "US"))
        (.getNationalNumber us-number))
      (catch NumberParseException e
        nil))))

(println (parse-phone-no "5"))
```

If I run it with a generic `catch Exception` then it works fine, however any combination of `catch NumberParseException`, `catch PhoneNumberUtil/NumberParseException`, and `catch (.NumberParseException phoneUtil)` gives a `Unable to resolve classname` error. I'd like to catch the custom exception and let others slide, so I'd appreciate your help.

Thanks, Kevin

Comment: You should also consider using `let` instead of `def` to create local variables (in this context "consider" means: "absolutely do this, but if you're still learning Clojure you can put it off for a while"). Amazingly, I can't find a SO question to link you to at the moment: sorry.

Comment: Maybe ask one and answer it yourself? Because yeah, I know my syntax is really crappy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like `PhoneNumberUtil`, You need to either `import` the `NumberParseException` to the namespace or provide its full qualified package in the catch expression.

If the exception is an inner class, that translates in clojure to OuterClass$InnerClass (which you still need to either import or qualify with its package).